# LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmic already defined

Tags: latex, submission

I wrote my first paper in overleaf and I am about to submit it to arXiv. To do so, i go through 'submit' on the webpage, however, I get 3 errors, which I do not understand well.

```
> LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmic already defined.
> 
> Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
> 
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
> <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
> 
>                                                    l.112    }
>           % Your command was ignored. Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command, or  <return>  to continue without it.
> 
> ) Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the
> `algorithmicx' style )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/empheq.sty
> Package: empheq 2017/03/31 v2.15 Emphasizing equations
> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty
> Package: mhsetup 2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH) )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
> Package: mathtools 2022/02/07 v1.28a mathematical typesetting tools
> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty Package:
> calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ) \calc@Acount=\count291
> \calc@Bcount=\count292 \calc@Adimen=\dimen173 \calc@Bdimen=\dimen174
> \calc@Askip=\skip58 \calc@Bskip=\skip59 LaTeX Info: Redefining
> \setlength on input line 80. LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on
> input line 81. \calc@Ccount=\count293 \calc@Cskip=\skip60 )
> \g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count294 \l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen175
> \origjot=\skip61 \l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen176
> \l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen177
> \l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen178
> \l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen179
> \l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen180
> \l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen181 \xmathstrut@box=\box57
> \xmathstrut@dim=\dimen182 ) \l_EQ_equationtype_int=\count295
> \l_EQ_alignmentmode_int=\count296 \l_EQ_totalwidth_dim=\dimen183
> \l_EQ_displaywidth_dim=\dimen184 \l_EQ_temp_linewidth_dim=\dimen185
> \l_EQ_linewidth_dim=\dimen186 \EmphEqdelimitershortfall=\dimen187
> \EmphEqdelimiterfactor=\count297 \g_EQ_toptag_height_dim=\dimen188
> \g_EQ_bottomtag_depth_dim=\dimen189 \g_EQ_toprow_height_dim=\dimen190
> \g_EQ_bottomrow_depth_dim=\dimen191 \g_EQ_widesttag_dim=\dimen192
> \EQ_mathdisplay_box=\box58 \EQ_tag_box=\box59
> \g_EQ_temprow_int=\count298 )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
> Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
```

Second:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
...
```

Third one:

```
Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
...
```

Comment: You are probably loading multiple incompatible algorithm packages, but without seeing a [mre] that's just a guess